# Unable to create a file inside a temporary directory Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wanted to use a temporary directory to create files into it but it just would not work until I put the code directly inside the "main". I would like to know why.

This code does not want to work, telling me "no such file or directory":

```py
def use_temp_directory():
    tmpdir = tempfile.TemporaryDirectory()
    os.chdir(tmpdir.name)
    return tmpdir.name

if __name__ == "__main__":
    _ = use_temp_directory()
    create_file(filepath="./somefile.txt", mode="w")
```

This code do work:

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    tmpdir = tempfile.TemporaryDirectory()
    os.chdir(tmpdir.name)
    create_file(filepath="./somefile.txt", mode="w")
```

For me both codes are the same, what I am missing?

Comment: I guess the temporary directory is only there till the calling process/scope ends. So your function finishes and the directory is destroyed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as just-learned-it commented, from documentation:

`tempfile.TemporaryDirectory(suffix=None, prefix=None, dir=None)`

This function securely creates a temporary directory using the same rules as mkdtemp(). The resulting object can be used as a context manager (see Examples). ***On completion of the context or destruction of the temporary directory object the newly created temporary directory and all its contents are removed from the filesystem***.

Comment: Oh that is what I missed! The temporary directory object... thanks and thanks to just-learned-it, too

Answer (score 4):

You only return the name of the directory, however the directory itself, `tmpdir`, runs out of scope when the function returns and is hence removed.

You can use `TemporaryDirectory` as a context manager which will remove the directory upon exit:

```
with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as td:
    # do something with `td` which is the name of the directory
```

Comment: I know we can do that but I had reasons not to use this

Comment: "... which is the name of the directory"
This part may be obvious, but for some reason I thought that td would be some OS-level identifier of the directory - I tried to find methods on the thing but there were none.